# How to solve Eventstream overflow auto discard last event for playframework 1.2.7

Tags: playframework

The EventStream is limited to about 100 messages

```
 ArchivedEventStream<Event> chatEvents = new ArchivedEventStream<Event>(100);
```

When overflow, how to work correctly for my webapp?

Or any method can instead ArchivedEventStream ?

Or how to add EventStream default size ?

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a poll request for fixing eventStream with websockets in play master branch which is being looked at.

https://github.com/playframework/play1/pull/709

The fix is now only for Websockets and not ArchivedEventStream.  You can comment at the above link to make it for both if you desire.